# iOS app crash at launch iOS 10 using XCode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, ios10, xcode11, xcode11.3, xcode11.4

I am getting an error when launching the app. I am building the app using XCode 11.3.1 and running app on iOS 10.3.1

App crash it does not even call `didfinishlaunch`

This is what I see in crash report

Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AuthenticationServices.framework/AuthenticationServices | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/09070F2C-D2BA-46DB-9438-6219F18ABBEF/WhiteLabel.app/WhiteLabel | Reason: image not found

Comment: Your Facebook app not correctly setup by your project bundle id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthenticationServices.framework is iOS 12+, it is not available on iOS 10.3.1:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices